# Burninate [15-characters]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Currently there exists a special case of [character-limit](/questions/tagged/character-limit), namely [15-characters](/questions/tagged/15-characters). The latter refers explicitly to the minimum length of comments. Seeing the relative low amount of questions on the latter tag (only 9), and that there already is an appropriate way to indicate a question is in regard to comments ([comments](/questions/tagged/comments)). I think we should burninate [15-characters](/questions/tagged/15-characters).

Comment: Or just remove [tag:15-characters]?

Comment: Yes.‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏

Comment: Seeing there are no answers yet, Ill redress this as a burnination question then. @StopHarmingMonica

Comment: Burnination is way overkill. With such a small tag, going through it and manually retagging the questions is doable for a single person in a few minutes. Then the tag will, if not re-used, be deleted by the system after a day.

Comment: @DanielFischer I agree, but perhaps someone comes up with a valid reason not to remove the tag. I'd rather hear that now then javing to undo the changes later.

Comment: Quite. That's why I haven't started editing yet.

Comment: [status-burninated]!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think so too.

In fact, I'm going to take the liberty to change all the questions with this tag to use [character-limit](/questions/tagged/character-limit) instead.

[character-limit](/questions/tagged/character-limit) describes all of the questions much better than [15-characters](/questions/tagged/15-characters) does.

Comment: I'd rather see you wait a few days, in case anyone brings up any valid concerns as why not to do this.

Comment: @Luuklag No, not really, It's [tag:status-completed] now anyways, *fait accompli*.

Comment: Also next time a more informative edit description would be helpful, @JL2210

Comment: @Luuklag Whoops, sorry. Will do.